# How can I fade the height of an element smoothly?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I try to fade out my elements on click. But the problem is, I want it smoothly but the height is kind of jumping after fading. Is there an option for like fading smoothly vertically?

Here's a Stack Snippet:

```js
$(".collapse-content").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).closest(".collapse-head").hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$('.collapse-head').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("blockquote").css({
            "color": "#000"
        });
    },

    function() {
        $(this).find("blockquote").css({
            "color": "#777"
        });
    }
);
$(".collapse-head").click(function() {
    $(".collapse-head").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".collapse-content").fadeOut("slow");
    $(this).find(".collapse-content").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
.collapse-head {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-text mb-50 mb-sm-20">
    <div class="row collapse-head active" data-id="1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 collapse-title">
            <blockquote>
                <p>
                    A
                </p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div id="1" class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 mb-xs-30 collapse-content" data-text="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
            sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
            rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse-head" style="margin-top:20px" data-id="2">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 collapse-title">
            <blockquote>
                <p>
                    B
                </p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 mb-xs-30 collapse-content" data-text="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
            sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
            rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse-head" style="margin-top:20px" data-id="3">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 collapse-title">
            <blockquote>
                <p>
                    C
                </p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-sm-50 mb-xs-30 collapse-content" data-text="">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
            sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
            rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Also a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8nqsdkvg/

Comment: Looks like you want a combination of `.fadeOut()` and `.slideUp()` (https://jsfiddle.net/stzfyhgu/) - there's no built-in method for this, but you could combine animate height with opacity to create one easily enough.

Comment: Any of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+fade+and+slide

Comment: hi, you can give value to fadeIn as in = fadein(1400) as well as fadeOut. is that what you mean?

Comment: @Klikdesainweb No, tested it, but still at the end of the fade the font jumps

Comment: take a look at my answer. I have no idea again. How about add some css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @freedomn-m says is true, but I think the problem is in `.collapse content`. How about this one?

```
$(".collapse-head").click(function() {
    $(".collapse-head").removeClass("active");
    $(".collapse-content").slideUp(1400);
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".collapse-content").fadeOut(1400);
    $(this).find(".collapse-content").fadeIn(1400);
});
```

I add `slideUp` for `.collapse-content` `$(".collapse-content").slideUp(1400);`

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kaopLe37/)